# Exclusão de registro em tabelas em cascata

Tags: sql

Tenho uma tabela "Termos" que seu ID é FK de "TermosExpressao".

Conforme mostrado na figura abaixo.

Quando vou executar o comando "delete Termos where IDTermo = 4" o sql me gera

o seguinte erro.

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_TermoExpressao_Termos1". The conflict occurred in database
>   "SprintJuncao", table "dbo.TermoExpressao", column 'IDTermoExpressao'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Pelo que li me parece que isso é uma exclusão em cascata, quando eu excluir os registro de  "Termos" automaticamente devo excluir os registros relacionados á "TermosExpressao",
No caso todos os registro em TermosExpressao com IDTermo = 4

Alguém pode me ajudar como devo proceder nesse caso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: terás que excluir primeiro os dados da tabela `TermoExpressao`, podes fazer assim `delete dbo.TermoExpressao where IDTermo = 4`

Comment: Outra coisa que poderias fazer, seria alterar a tua FK para ser `delete cascade`

Comment: @PabloVargas Eu acho que o correto no meu caso seria esse delete cascade, como procedo para fazer isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A melhor solução então é alterar sua FK para que ela seja `delete cascade`

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TermoExpressao] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_TermoExpressao_Termos1]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TermoExpressao]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_TermoExpressao_Termos1] FOREIGN KEY([IDTermo])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Termo] ([IDTermo])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TermoExpressao] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_TermoExpressao_Termos1]
GO
```

outra opção, para resolver isso seria modificar a sua FK conforme as imagens.

[image: Modificar FK]

[image: Delete cascade]

Comment: a FK_TermosExpressao_Termos já está dessa forma. Tem outra FK_TermosExpressao_Termos1 que referencia IDTermosExpressao ao IDTermos. Sem isto, será que o erro está sendo gerado ai?

Comment: Provavelmente, terás que por em ambas suas FK o `delete cascade`