# Excluir dados de tabela em cascata

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, inner

tenho alguns relacionamentos em minhas tabelas e estou querendo excluir de forma inversa.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

em meu sistema o usuário terá a opção de excluir uma categoria, ai vem minha dúvida como vou fazer isso pois deverá excluir as paginas dá categoria as descrições da pagina as imagens da pagina e a descrição da imagem, estou utilizando PDO e php preciso de alguma sugestão, com inner join ele traz apenas dados completos ou seja de todas as tabelas relacionadas povoadas e com left join traz dados repetidos na tabela de edição por exemplo se eu tiver uma categoria comidas e dentro eu tiver diversas paginas referenciando essa categoria irá trazer aquela categoria repetidas vezes na edição e acredito que isso não seria agradável para o usuário.

obrigado.

Comment: Você tem chaves estrangeiras definidas do lado do MySQL?

Comment: Se você tiver chaves estrangeiras, pode fazer um delete cascade. ex: uma vez removida a categoria bebidas, todos os produtos que forem bebidas serão removidos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer algo tipo

```
ALTER TABLE pagina ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_categoria_pagina) REFERENCES categoria_pagina (id_categoria_pagina) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE descricao_pagina ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_pagina) REFERENCES pagina (id_pagina) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE imagem ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_pagina) REFERENCES pagina (id_pagina) ON DELETE CASCADE;
ALTER TABLE descricao_imagem ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_imagem) REFERENCES imagem (id_imagem) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Aí você não precisa mexer em nada no lado do PHP — quando você apagar alguma coisa os penduricalhos vão todos juntos.

(Não sei qual programa você usou pra gerar essa imagem bonitinha na sua pergunta, mas ele muito provavelmente tem alguma funcionalidade pra gerar esses comandos que eu escrevi automaticamente.)

## Veja também

- [FOREIGN KEY](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/foreign-keys/) no MariaDB (inglês);
- [pergunta relacionada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42747/exclus%C3%A3o-de-registro-em-tabelas-em-cascata), relativa ao SQL Server.

Comment: então mas isso vai funcionar no mysql?

Comment: foi o mysql workbach

Comment: Sim; pra maioria das coisas, MariaDB = MySQL.

Comment: acabei de achar o problema do sistema, e mais complicado do que parecia, problema com left join pois tem relacionamento um para muitos

Comment: e quando se trata de uma tabela com apenas um dado em cada estou conseguindo deletar mas quando por ex: tenho duas imagens em uma tabela estou com problema para trazer estes dois id

Comment: Eu estou perdido. Pode editar a sua pergunta colocando, e.g. as consultas que você está tentando, o que elas estão retornando, e o que você gostaria que elas retornassem?

Comment: Consegui resolver com left join, o que acha... poderia melhorar?

Comment: agora que entendi sua resposta ficou super correta.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui desenvolver um método para conseguir carregar os dados para exclusão, fiz da seguinte forma:

```
public function tableCategoria() {
    $consulta = PDOUtil::getStance()->prepare("SELECT categoria_pagina.id_categoria_pagina as cat_id, categoria_pagina.nome as c_nome,
    pagina.id_pagina as p_id, pagina.tema, pagina.data, pagina.id_categoria_pagina,
    descricao_pagina.id_descricao_pagina, descricao_pagina.sub_titulo, descricao_pagina.texto_da_pagina, descricao_pagina.id_pagina as d_Id_pag,
    imagem.id_imagem, imagem.nome as img_nome, imagem.tipo, imagem.tamanho, imagem.id_pagina as img_id_pagina,
    descricao_imagem.id_descricao_imagem, descricao_imagem.titulo, descricao_imagem.texto_da_imagem, descricao_imagem.id_imagem
    FROM categoria_pagina
    left JOIN pagina ON (pagina.id_categoria_pagina = categoria_pagina.id_categoria_pagina)
    left JOIN descricao_pagina ON (descricao_pagina.id_pagina = pagina.id_pagina)
    left JOIN imagem ON(imagem.id_pagina = pagina.id_pagina)
    left JOIN descricao_imagem ON(descricao_imagem.id_imagem = imagem.id_imagem)
    group by c_nome");
    $consulta->execute();
    while ($linha = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        echo '<thead>';
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $linha->cat_id . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $linha->c_nome . '</td>';

        echo ' <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pagina=alterarCategoria&id_categoria='
        . $linha->cat_id. '&nome_categoria='.$linha->c_nome.'">Editar</a>';
        echo ' <a class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-apagar" href="index.php?pagina=../controller/controllerCategoria&id_categoria='
        . $linha->cat_id . '&nome_categoria='.$linha->c_nome.'&id_imagem='.$linha->id_imagem.'&nome_imagem='.$linha->img_nome.'&id_pagina=' . $linha->p_id .'&acao=deletar">Deletar</a></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
        echo '</thead>';
    }
}
```

dessa forma consigo carregar todos os ids para minha exclusão.